# How to change the order of independent variables by using package stargazer

Tags: r

I am running some regressions. I considered the fixed effects. When I am about to convert it to latex, I found that I don't know how to change the order of my independent variables. The fixed effects has ten levels, from D1 to D10.

```
reg_1 <- lm(R_it_RF ~ Mkt_RF, data = data)

reg_2 <- lm(R_it_RF ~ Mkt_RF + i - 1, data = data %>% arrange(i))

stargazer(reg_1, reg_2, type = 'text', title="Results", align=TRUE)
```

My result is like this:

```
Results
========================================================================
                                    Dependent variable:                 
                    ----------------------------------------------------
                                          R_it_RF                       
                               (1)                        (2)           
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Mkt_RF                       1.064***                  1.064***         
                             (0.026)                    (0.026)         

iD1                                                     -0.088          
                                                        (1.457)         

iD10                                                     1.151          
                                                        (1.457)         

iD2                                                     -0.257          
                                                        (1.457)         

iD3                                                      0.371          
                                                        (1.457)         

iD4                                                      1.326          
                                                        (1.457)         

iD5                                                     -0.282          
                                                        (1.457)         

iD6                                                      0.674          
                                                        (1.457)         

iD7                                                     -0.410          
                                                        (1.457)         

iD8                                                      1.430          
                                                        (1.457)         

iD9                                                      1.064          
                                                        (1.457)         

Constant                      0.498                                     
                             (0.487)                                    

------------------------------------------------------------------------
Observations                   550                        550           
R2                            0.751                      0.780          
Adjusted R2                   0.750                      0.775          
Residual Std. Error     10.661 (df = 548)          10.728 (df = 539)    
F Statistic         1,650.243*** (df = 1; 548) 173.308*** (df = 11; 539)
========================================================================
Note:                                        *p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01
```

I want to change the order of independent variables, say from D1 to D10.

I would be appreciate if you could give me some suggustions.

Comment: Look up the documentation on the `stargazer` function and in particular the `order` argument.

Comment: Changing the Mkt_RF variable to numeric - would have to strip out the first two characters (iD) - then it will probably be in the order you want.

Comment: @caldwellst You are right. It works. Thank you very much. I am not familiar with the function.

Comment: @markhogue Thank you very much. You method can also solve my dumb problem. Very practical.